# PHP to extract price from string

Tags: php

I have an array with strings inside of it. Each string is different in composition, but each has a price in it.

An example string is below.

"10/22 I-TAC 22LR TACTICAL TALO GREY - $299.99 shipped"

I am trying to remove the price from this string and create this.

"10/22 I-TAC 22LR TACTICAL TALO GREY - shipped"

I have tried regex functions and even trying to come up with a custom functions, but I just can't figure it out.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this expression](http://regex101.com/r/zM1mE5):

```
[$]\d+[\d,.]*\s*
```

Matches a dollar sign (`[$]`), followed by at least one digit (`\d+`), followed by any additional digits/decimals/commas (`[\d,.]*`), finally followed by any additional whitespace.

I left the decimal/comma parsing up in the air, because some countries format like: `$1.999,99`.

In PHP, use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
echo preg_replace('/[$]\d+[\d,.]*\s*/', '', '10/22 I-TAC 22LR TACTICAL TALO GREY - $299.99 shipped');
// 10/22 I-TAC 22LR TACTICAL TALO GREY - shipped
```

Comment: Do any countries that reverse dot and comma use the US dollar sign?

Comment: Very valid point, I used a character class so you could include Euros, etc as well.  Granted, doesn't seem like it was necessary for the scope of the question..but the OP didn't really specify one way or the  other.

Answer (score 6):

```
preg_replace('/\$\d+\.\d{2}\s*/', '', $string);
```

This removes a dollar sign followed by digits, followed by a decimal point, 2 more digits, and optional whitespace.

You might need to tweak this if you display prices with commas, or the cents are optional.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure of the order ( isn't very recommended ) you can try to explode the string and validate that such string chunk starts with "$"

```
$str = "xx xxx xx xx $1235.00";
$str = explode($str," ");
$num = ($str[4][0] == "$") ? str_replace("$","", $str[4]) : 0.00;
```

I haven't tested but this shoud do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) always good to see a non-regex solution in the mix.